# Integer to Roman Numeral converter

Tags: c++, roman-numerals

I have implemented an Integer to Roman Numeral converter that converts any number in the range \$[1 \le x \le4999]\$ to its Roman number equivalent. Any comments on improving my code style or organization?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Solution{
public:
    Solution () : IntVal {1,5,10,50,100,500,1000} , roman {'I', 'V' , 'X', 'L' ,'C', 'D' ,'M'} {}
    std::string intToRoman(int num);
private:
    int IntVal[7];
    char roman[7];
    int fslt(int num);
    std::string output;
    void helper(int num);
    void postProcess();
    void str_replace( std::string &s, const std::string &search, const std::string &replace);
};


#include "roman.hpp"

int Solution::fslt(int num){
    if (num>=50){
        if (num<100) return 3;
        else if (num>=100 && num < 500) return 4;
        else if (num>=500 && num < 1000) return 5;
        else return 6;
    }
    else{ // num < 50
        if (num>=10) return 2;
        else if (num>=5) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
}

void Solution::helper (int num){
    int div = fslt(num);


    if (div == 0){
        for (int i = 0; i <num ;i++){
            output += roman[div];
        }
         return;
    }
    else {
        int rn = fslt(num);
        int numTimes = num/IntVal[rn];
        for (int i=0;i < numTimes; i++){
            output += roman[rn];
        }
        helper(num-numTimes*IntVal[rn]);
    }
}

void Solution::postProcess(){
    str_replace(output, "DCCCC", "CM");
    str_replace(output, "CCCC", "CD");
    str_replace(output, "LXXXX", "XC");
    str_replace(output, "XXXX", "XL");

    str_replace(output, "VIIII", "IX");
    str_replace(output, "IIII", "IV");
}

std::string Solution::intToRoman(int num){
    Solution::helper(num);
    Solution::postProcess();
    return output;
}

void Solution::str_replace( std::string &s, const std::string &search, const std::string &replace)
{
     for( size_t pos = 0; ; pos += replace.length() ) 
    {
         pos = s.find( search, pos );
         if( pos == std::string::npos ) break;

         s.erase( pos, search.length() );
         s.insert( pos, replace );
     }
}

int main(){
    Solution mySol;
    std::cout <<  mySol.intToRoman(4999) << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Using three lookup tables, one for each of the last three digit would be much simpler.

Comment: here is one written for code golf. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/828/186

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Helper function too complex

Your `helper` function and the `fslt` function seem too complex for what they do (`helper` is even recursive!).  All you are really doing is adding roman numerals starting at the highest value first.  So something like this would suffice:

```
#define DIM(arr)        (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))

void Solution::helper (int num){
    for (int i = DIM(IntVal)-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        while (num >= IntVal[i]) {
            output += roman[i];
            num -= IntVal[i];
        }
    }
}
```